# How can death change the magic?

Tags: magic, death, life

My world is full of magic, even if it is not distributed equally in all areas. Most of magic is in the Cloudy mountains and their close surroundings.

It is present in every living being (flowers, trees, people, animals) but some gods (the Evil the Rider, the Good the Rider and the Nature), beings known as the Shining ones and few people (known as the Gifted ones) are capable to see magic, its changes and effects of those changes.

This allows them to see someone's death sooner than it becomes visible for common people.

But how anyone's death may change the magic?

Comment: What do you mean by "see someone's death"? They can tell if someone's dead without checking breathing or pulse?

Comment: This is pretty much asking for ideas, which is off-topic for this site, but might be a good conversation for the [chat] if you're up to it. Otherwise, this is pretty much an opinion-based question unless you add some desired effects and even then I'm not sure it'd be a good fit.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you are asking here. I tried to parse the question and failed. What change? With respect to who or what?

Comment: I presume you mean something like an aura surrounding a living being. In which case, it could be imagined as changing colour. One colour when alive, another colour death. Perhaps with some minature fireworks to mark the passage of the soul or magic power leaking out at the moment of death.

Comment: Do you mean that their death changes how their "aura" looks like to those that can see it? Or how the death of someone affects the "aura" of others close to them? I don't see why my aura would change because of my nearing death if I am not ill or very old and have a slowly fading aura. If someone stabs me with a knife I would expect my aura to be absolutely normal until the knife enters my body, then maybe flare up for a moment or be concentrated in the entry wound to try and heal the damage and then fade away quite fast. Could you add some sort of "timeline" of the events and who watches them

Comment: "But how anyone's death may change the magic?" What is it supposed to do? We don't know how magic works and what it can do. The answer can be anything we can think of or maybe it does nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

You note that magic is in all living things:

> It is present in every living being (flowers, trees, people, animals)

If beings that are able to see magic would be able to see when the magic that is in the living being has gone.  This would of course depend on what the nature of magic looks like to these creatures but they would see it leaching out of the individual as the life force also is seeping from the creature.

Perhaps this is represented by dimming of color or an absence of light in the way that heat shows up on infrared scans as red turning to white bright spots and cold is reflected as blue turning to blackness.